# Swift Firebase access data inside child snapshot (by childAdded)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I posted a question previously regarding how to access data inside a child snapshot, where I got a very well-working answer. However, this solution only allowed me to retrieve the data by value - and not my child. You see, I had a JSON tree-structure like this:

```
Players {

PlayerID {

Username

Rank

Achievements {

Rookie: yes

}


}
```

And then I realized that I really need multiple 'childByAutoId' under the 'Achievements' - that will look something like this:

```
Player {

PlayerID {

Username

Rank

Achievements {

autoID1 {

isAchieved: yes

}

autoID2 {

isAchieved: yes 

}

}

}
```

So how would I go on trying to grab the very ChildValues of each childByAutoId? I know for a fact that this works with the 'ChildAdded' on observe Snapshot, however - this doesn't seem to be a feature here.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
 if let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Achievements") as? FIRDataSnapshot{

                if let achievementDictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] , achievementDictionary.count > 0{

                    if let achieveMedal = achievementDictionary["Rookie"] as? String {

                        print(achieveMedal)

             }        
       }
    }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a JSON tree structure like this:-

```
Achievements : {

 achievement1 : true,
 achievement2 : true,
 achievement3 : false,
 achievement4 : true,

}
```

For retrieving your achievements:-

```
if let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Achievements") as? FIRDataSnapshot{

            if let achievementDictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] , achievementDictionary.count > 0{

               for each in achievementDictionary{
                  print(each.0) // achievement name
                  print(each.1)  // isAchieved (true/false)
               }

         }        
   }
}
```

It's not advisable to add such deep nodes in your DB for navigation reason's .

But this code will also work for the `childByAutoID` case, i.e **`each.0`** will be your autoID AND **`each.1`** will become that id's corresponding dictionary.For deeper details of that dictionary just navigate through the dictionary

Comment: The problem is that I need to provide some more data inside each 'childByAutoId' that I also am in need of. Hmmm.. Is it not possible?